# In android webview, how do you not allow zoom out

Tags: android, webview, pinchzoom, zooming

I want to let my user zoom in on a web page my app is serving to it's web view. 
But I don't want them to be able to zoom out past 100%.

Part of what my app presents to the user is a JPG. Users may wish to view this JPG in more detail, but I've noticed that they can also zoom out past the 100% mark.  It sort of looks like it stops at 25% but that's just a guess.

Question: is there a way to change the min zoom size from 25% to 100%? 
Note I do not want to turn off zooming, I just don't want to let them zoom out too much.

Answer (score 0):

just extend WebView and override zoomIn and zoomOut to keep track of the zoom level and block zoomOut when return to 100%

your code can look like this

```
class MyWebView extends WebView {
 private int mZoomIn;
   .... view consturctors
 @Override
 public boolean zoomIn(){
     boolean ok = super.zoomIn();
     if(ok){
           mZoomIn++;
     }
     return ok;
 }
 @Override
 public boolean zoomOut(){
        if (mZoomIn == 0) {
          return false;
        }
      boolean ok = super.zoomOut();
      if (ok) {
         mZoomIn --;
     }
 }

}
```